# How can i check array in if loop in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I have problem with if loop in array.I am working in Ginger bread source code and modify email app but problem in if loop in array.Show my code.

```
String[] arrayUri;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_compose);
    //getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.list_title);
    Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    arrayUri=b.getStringArray("uriList");
    //data1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("hello");
    mController = Controller.getInstance(getApplication());
    mListener = new Listener();
    initViews();
    if(arrayUri != null) //Not Working
    {
      makeToast("Hello");
    }
```

I used this one

```
    if(!arrayUri.equals("")) //Not Working
    {
      makeToast("Hello");
    }


    if(arrayUri.length >0) //Not Working
    {
      makeToast("Hello");
    }

    if(arrayUri.length != 0) //Not Working
    {
      makeToast("Hello");
    }
```

Over all condition are not working in email app. any other way to compare array in if.

Comment: what if arrayUri=b.getStringArray("uriList"); returns null?

Comment: "Not working" isn't a good description of what you're seeing. What's happening compared with what you expected?

Comment: `arrayUri` is an array of String, so `!arrayUri.equals("")` will always return false as you compare it with a String.

Comment: It should work, better you post the error or exception to understand the problem clearly.

Comment: This one is Ginger bread MailComposeActivity.java. I want to use this activity in contact.it's execute perfectly in contact app. but it's not working properly in email app. It's generate error Null pointer Exception

Comment: What doe this have to do with Swing?  Removing tag.

Comment: Swing is in java and android based on java. i have logical issues that way in swing . May be in Swing you used array as well as if okk

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this (I'm 80% certain it'll work)

But it should get you on the path to an answer.

```
if (arrayUri.getClass().isArray()) {
  // I'm an array
} else {
  // I'm not an array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(arrayUri == null || arrayUri.length == 0){
   toast("ARRAY EMPTY OR NULL");
} else {
   toast("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array into arrayList. It might help you. You can try this.

```
ArrayList<String> lst;

     for(int i = 0; i < arrayUri.length; i++ )
     {
         lst.add(arrayUri[i]);
     }

if(lst.isEmpty())
     {

     }
```

Hope this will help you...